# Syntax error in batch script if not exist command is used

Tags: batch-file

I'm getting a syntax error in the below script, Can someone help me? I'm a novice in batch scripting.

```
Error log: 

The syntax of the command is incorrect.

E:\Apps\Console\BatchFile>IF NOT EXIST "!FileDestinationLocation!\IDH-DailyCycle-Trade.file"
```

Code:

```
ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion


SET "Stat=A"
SET FileDestinationLocation=%1
echo %Stat% -here
ECHO:
IF NOT EXIST "!FileDestinationLocation!\IDH-DailyCycle-Trade.file"
( 
SET "Stat=B"
echo %Stat% -here
ECHO Missing Daily Cycle-Trade File 
)
IF NOT EXIST "!FileDestinationLocation!IDH-DailyCycle-Security.file"    
( 
SET "Stat=B" 
ECHO Missing Daily Cycle-Security File
)
IF NOT EXIST "!FileDestinationLocation!IDH-DailyCycle-Issuer.file"      
( 
SET "Stat=B"
ECHO Missing Daily Cycle-Issuer File
)
IF NOT EXIST     "!FileDestinationLocation!IDH-DailyCycle-IssuerUC.file"    
( 
SET "Stat=B"
ECHO Missing Daily Cycle-IssueUC File
)


if %Stat% EQU "A"
ECHO All files available for Daily Cycle


DEL /q "!FileDestinationLocation!*.*"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO CNT
: CNT
ECHO "Process Completed"
```

Comment: The help file for the `IF` command clearly describes the correct syntax for using parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with your code, as already alluded to, was that your opening parentheses must be on the same line as their preceding code, and separated by at least one space character, i.e. `IF [condition] (`

However, there were a few other inconsistencies, which I've tried to address in the rewrite below.

```batch-file
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "FileDestinationLocation=%~1"
IF NOT DEFINED FileDestinationLocation (
    EXIT /B 1
) ELSE (
    IF "%FileDestinationLocation:~-1%" == "\" (
        SET "FileDestinationLocation=%FileDestinationLocation:~,-1%"
    )
)
IF NOT EXIST "%FileDestinationLocation%\" (
    ECHO Input directory does not exist
    EXIT /B 1
)

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    SET "Stat=A"
    ECHO %Stat% -here
    ECHO=
    IF NOT EXIST "!FileDestinationLocation!\IDH-DailyCycle-Trade.file" (
        SET "Stat=B"
        ECHO !Stat! -here
        ECHO Missing Daily Cycle-Trade File
    )
    IF NOT EXIST "!FileDestinationLocation!\IDH-DailyCycle-Security.file" (
        SET "Stat=B"
        ECHO Missing Daily Cycle-Security File
    )
    IF NOT EXIST "!FileDestinationLocation!\IDH-DailyCycle-Issuer.file" (
        SET "Stat=B"
        ECHO Missing Daily Cycle-Issuer File
    )
    IF NOT EXIST "!FileDestinationLocation!\IDH-DailyCycle-IssuerUC.file" (
        SET "Stat=B"
        ECHO Missing Daily Cycle-IssueUC File
    )
    IF "%Stat%" EQU "A" ECHO All files available for Daily Cycle
    DEL /A /F /Q "!FileDestinationLocation!\*.*" 2> NUL
    ECHO "Process Completed"
ENDLOCAL

GOTO :EOF
```

I have not enabled delayed exapansion at the beginning of the script, to ensure that input arguments which have `!` characters are still passed without modification as the intended directory name.

I have also incorporated some code to ensure that input arguments, with, or without, trailing backslashes are treated equally. *(You had some instances of `!FileDestinationLocation!IDH-DailyCycle-…` and some of `!FileDestinationLocation!\IDH-DailyCycle-…`)*

The script is closed if the input directory was not provided or does not exist.

I have indented the script for readability, and also improved the `DEL` command options to allow for the deletion regardless of the files' attributes, *(subject to permissions)*.

Answer (score 0):

The opening parentheses needs to be on the same line as the `IF` keyword.

Like this:

```batch-file
ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion


SET "Stat=A"
SET FileDestinationLocation=%1
echo %Stat% -here
ECHO:

IF NOT EXIST "!FileDestinationLocation!\IDH-DailyCycle-Trade.file" ( 
SET "Stat=B"
echo !Stat! -here
ECHO Missing Daily Cycle-Trade File 
)

IF NOT EXIST "!FileDestinationLocation!IDH-DailyCycle-Security.file" ( 
SET "Stat=B" 
ECHO Missing Daily Cycle-Security File
)

IF NOT EXIST "!FileDestinationLocation!IDH-DailyCycle-Issuer.file" ( 
SET "Stat=B"
ECHO Missing Daily Cycle-Issuer File
)

IF NOT EXIST     "!FileDestinationLocation!IDH-DailyCycle-IssuerUC.file" ( 
SET "Stat=B"
ECHO Missing Daily Cycle-IssueUC File
)


if "%Stat%" EQU "A" (
ECHO All files available for Daily Cycle


DEL /q "!FileDestinationLocation!*.*"


IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO CNT
)

: CNT
ECHO "Process Completed"
```

Comment: Verily, but the `if %Stat% EQU "A"` line also needs to be fixed. It's not clear which of the following lines need to be executed when `stat` has value `A` - I made a guess. The block needs to start with `(` on the `if` line however. If only one line is required to be executed on condition-true, then that line must begin on the `if` line if the `(statement-sequence)` structure is not employed (probably not in this case, though). The `if` arguments need to have *both* sides of the operator quoted, or neither, not "one but not t'other".

Comment: @Magoo, line `12` should read `echo !Stat! -here`, not `echo %Stat% -here`.

Comment: @Compo - Yes, I missed that; fixed now.  Not happy with triple-backtick formatting - not so good as revamped old method, so fixed that, too.